# What does Grep */* mean in KSH

Tags: grep, ksh

In `ksh`, what does `grep */*[myPattern]` mean?

Answer (score 1):

The shell expands `*/*[myPattern]` and then `grep` interprets the first word of the expansion as a pattern and the rest as filenames (except unless any of the file names happen to look like `grep` command options).  This is pretty much the same way it works in every common shell.